# MVC4 Application Best Approach to add multiple items from database to a model

Tags: database-design, asp.net-mvc-4, model

I'm working on a project for a class. I am creating a meal planner app that allows you to add products to a database then you select products to include in a meal and the meals can be added to a meal plan that you can view by a weekly schedule.

I've got the products set up and can add these to the database (that's the easy part) so my question is what is the best approach to add products to a meal.

Meal Model:

```
public class Meal
{
    public int MealId { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Products { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Creator")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Product Model:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int UnitId { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public Boolean Included { get; set; }

    public virtual Unit unit { get; set; }
}
```

I thought about adding the bool to the product model to signal when it is selected but not sure how I would include that in many different meals. I didn't want to create different products for each meal as that seemed to defeat the purpose of having a database to hold products.

Not quite sure how to proceed. I would also assume that however I solve this I can apply this same principle to the meal to meal plans scenario. Any suggestions to point me in the right direction?

Comment: In your question title you said `add multiple items from database to a model`, then you said in your question `adding the bool to the product model to signal when it is selected` seems like you're talking two different areas of your application. So which one is your problem? Getting inputs from the UI or showing a list of product to the UI using your model?

Comment: Sorry I was just throwing out what I was thinking at the time. Actually I need to show a list of products that user can select from to add to a meal. I believe @Sav is got me heading in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understand, you seem to be looking for a many to many relationship between the two tables. I'm no db engineer, but i think you probably need an intermediary table that can act as a link between the meals and products tables. Something like:

```
public class ProductInMeals
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int MealId { get; set; }

    /* Any other fields you want to associate with this relationship */
}
```

So you end up with a table with 2 foreign keys. It may be worth adding a primary key and a few more details about the relationship, but that's really up to you.

Comment: So you end up creating a table that has many entries that list a mealId and a ProductId and there may be for example 5 entries for the same meal each with a different productId for each. Then when displaying the meal, I would poll this dbTable and retrieve the info based on this table to display in a view. I would assume then I should create a viewModel that contains the mealId and a List<Products> to send to a view so all the data can be strongly typed?

Comment: Yes, so your query would essentially have 2 parts: Meal -> ProductInMeal -> Product. If you're using MVC4, a Linq query could probably do this quite easily. You also have the ability to go the other way, and find all the meals that contain a particular product with the same query in reverse.